# I'm trying to Traverse the shakespeare graph on Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to traverse the Shakespeare graph on Neo4j to display Julius Caesar and the fact it was performed twice.

This is the query I am using

```
START n=node:node_auto_index(title = 'Julias Caesar')
MATCH (n)<-[:PERFORMED]-(play)
WHERE n.title = "Julias Caesar"
RETURN play, n
```

Answer (score 1):

As 'Julias Caesar' is referenced by two plays, you'll need the DISTINCT keyword to display him only once.

```
START n=node:node_auto_index(title = 'Julias Caesar')
MATCH (n)<-[:PERFORMED]-(play)
WHERE n.title = "Julias Caesar"
RETURN DISTINCT n
```

You'll have to leave out the play nodes in the RETURN statement as well, otherwise the DISTINCT keyword has no use.